# Tag friends on post and location with javascript api

Tags: javascript, facebook

It's now possible to tag friends and location in feed post https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/03/07/building-better-stories-with-location-and-friends/ according to this link.

I would like to do it with the javascript api, with `FB.ui` method, so without the publish_stream authorization.

Does anybody know how I can do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well according to the docs, using an id of a place and adding the place parameter works on a graph api post. Unfortunately, after having tested this,it doesn't seem to be the case with the FB.ui method. It also looks like you cannot tag friends via this method either.

This page https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed shows all the properties available, and it doesn't look like place is one of them. So I think this isn't possible at the moment I'm afraid. Perhaps you could raise a bug request for them to add it in